# .getLatitude and .getLongitude not working

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and I am trying to make this application where I need location co-ordinates of my current position and show my position on the map. all the other parts of the app run quite well until just when ever I try to get the latitude and longitude from the fusedLocationApi. I have followed this tutorial [Get the Last Known Location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and have tried to implement it on Google Map Activity.

here is my java file:

```
    package com.example.deep.app_project;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;

    import android.location.Criteria;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

    public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements  GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener,
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,   GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

LocationManager lm;
TextView lt, ln;
String provider;
Location l;
double lon= 0, lat =0;
GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    client.connect();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

}
public void button_Map_Back(View v){

    Intent MainActivityIntent = new Intent(Map.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(MainActivityIntent);
    finish();

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    l = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(client);
    if (l != null) {
         lt.setText(String.valueOf(l.getLatitude()));
         ln.setText(String.valueOf(l.getLongitude()));
    }



}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
     @Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {



    lt.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
    ln.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
}
```

here is my .xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.deep.app_project" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
             Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
        -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Distance_timer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_distance_timer" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Journey_type"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_journey_type" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".prev_stat_fragment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_prev_stat_fragment" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Result"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_result" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".settings_fragment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings_fragment" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SimpleFragmentActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_simple_fragment" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Time_timer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_time_timer" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyD-LoJLRIyTF2mI5HdKULNk1QhBAQlhkRQ"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".Map"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >

    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: my question is why does the app crash when i add    lt.setText(String.valueOf(l.getLatitude())); ln.setText(String.valueOf(l.getLongitude()));

inside the onConnected method;

is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done this... and found it confusing to deal with varying different documentation.

I found it easier to use OnMyLocationChangeListener:

```
Activity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener
```

then Override onLocationChanged:

```
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

        LatLng pos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate mLoc = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder().target(pos).zoom(ZOOM_LEVEL).build());
        map.moveCamera(mLoc);

        mLocMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(TITLE)
                .snippet(SNIPPET)
                .position(pos)
                .draggable(true));
        mLocMarker.showInfoWindow();

        map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);

}
```

Comment: sorry sir this snippet is not giving me the present co-ordinates; i tried to get the latitude and longitude out from location.getLatitude and location.getLongitude but none helped out... however the app did not crash this time.. thank you and hope that you would help me out a little further.

Comment: this WILL give you the users location. Can you edit your question to show your new complete code ?

Comment: Sir i have edited the code and now you can see how i tried to use the getLatitude and getLongitude methods. the app does not crash but it also doe not show the lat and long on to the textfields.